# Присваивание переменной char элемента списка

Tags: java

В данном задании мне нужно выписать все буквы повторяющиеся в строке( регистр важен).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s="Key word";
    char[] ch= s.toCharArray();
    ArrayList a1= new ArrayList();
    int ln;

    for(int i=0; i<ch.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<ch.length; j++){

            ch1 = a1.get(1);
            if(ch[i] != ch1) {
                ln++;
            }
        if(a1.size()==ln) {
            a1.add(ch[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Однако при попытке присваивания ch1 = a1.get(1) генерируется ошибка. 
В чём проблема и как её решить?

Comment: Потому что в `a1` на первой итерации циклов нет элементов, и попытка взять второй элемент приводит к ошибке. А ещё я несколько раз перечитал код и так и не понял как эти "фокусы" с `a1` и `ln` могут помочь в решении задач. Если нужно найти дубликаты символов, достаточно сложить их в `HashMap<Character, Integer>`, в которой ключом будет символ, а значением - количество повторений этого символа. После чего выбрать только те символы из `HashMap`, значение для которых больше 1.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList al = new ArrayList();  --- тут у нас тип Object-ы

Сделай явное приведение

ch1 = (Object) a1.get(1);